# Where is the "Attributes" on the Cognito console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am simply trying to add a custom auth attribute for sign in.  The default Amplify methods accept username and password, I just want to add "company_name".  According to [the documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/authentication/managing-user-attributes/q/platform/js#writing-and-updating-standard-attributes), I should be able to "first open the Amazon Cognito dashboard:\nNext, click on **Attributes** in the left hand navigation and click **Add custom attribute.**" However I'm not seeing it.  How should I proceed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are screenshots of the root AWS console, not the AWS Cognito console. You need to search for "Cognito" not "attributes", then open the AWS Cognito console, then follow those instructions for adding attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each AWS service has its own management console, generally accessible thru the root console (search is done by click on Services or thru the search input).

Going thru the console:

1. Go to the Cognito admin console and click Manage User Pools
   [image: search console]
2. Select your user pool
   [image: select your user pool]
3. Go to attributes on the left panel
   [image: scroll down]
4. At the bottom of the main content (scroll down), you can view/edit custom attributes
   [image: custom attributes]

Answer (score -1):

I cd'ed to my project, and then copy and pasted the what turns out to be commands in the terminal.

[image]

Then I chose User Pool, then my browser opened up the correct url.

[image]